# How to update token in firebase using swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

A app can send notifications to remote devices using `server key` and device `InstanceToken`. Now as the `instanceToken` is something that keeps on changing every time the user installs the application. The app uses this `instanceToken` to send notification to other users.

How can the `instanceToken` be updated every time user uninstalls and installs the application, so that when other user sends notification its provided to the same user

Have seen the use of this method in AppDelegate in quite a few place, need a expert who can help in understanding the logic behind it or assist in crafting a better method

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: 
#selector(self.tokenRefreshNotification(notification:)), name: 
NSNotification.Name.InstanceIDTokenRefresh, object: nil)
```

The best resources that one could find is [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server#auth)
and video from firecast team [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A1SDBIViRtE&t=30s)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,  selector: #selector(self.getFcmToken),
    name: .firInstanceIDTokenRefresh,
    object: nil)

    func getFcmToken(notification: NSNotification) {
        guard let contents = FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token()
            else {
                return
        }
        print("InstanceID token: \(contents)")
        if let token = FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token(){
            print(token)
            SaveToDefaults().setFcmToken(token: token)
            self.hitPushNotificationSubcribeApi(token: token)
        }
```

or

```
func messaging(_ messaging: FIRMessaging, didRefreshRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {

   print(fcmToken)

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can monitor when the FCN Token has been changed using the following FCM Delegate Method:

```
func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didRefreshRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) { }
```